# Возможно ли одним fxFlex-ом добиться нужного вида?

Tags: angular2, flexbox, angular, angular4, angular5

Необходимо получить такой результат:
[image: fxFlex row wrap - Angular]

***Но проблема вот в чем:***

Если в блоке `fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="25px"`
для элемента задать `fxFlex="20"`, в строке вмещается **3 элемента, а не 4** из-за отступов `fxLayoutGap` в `25px`

В инспекторе смотрю для элемента задано `max-width: 20%`

Думал решить проблему таким образом, `fxFlex="calc(20% - 25px)"`, но в таком случае в инспекторе уже не максимальная ширина, а `min-width: calc(20% - 25px);` и вот что получается:
[image: FxFlex gap Angular]

`fxLayoutGap="25px grid"` также не решает даной задачи, добавляет лишний горизонтальный скролинг :(

***Как можно решить данную задачу ?***

*Код тут:* https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j3pgzp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно добиться, но для этого вам нужно использовать биндинги с медиа запросами:

```
fxFlex.gt-md="calc(20% - 25px)"
```

Где `gt-md` это `screen and (min-width: 1280px)`, а на меньшую ширину использовать другой медиа запрос, например:

```
fxFlex.lt-lg="calc(33% - 25px)"
```

Где `lt-lg` это `screen and (max-width: 1279px)`.

Но еще проблема в том, что вы оперируете процентами и 2 блока имеющих ширину 33% растянуться, это проблема самого пакета `flex-layout`, потому что биндинг `fxFlex` компилируется в `flex + min-width`.

Единственный workaround, который предлагает Каэрус Кару (лид `flex-layout`) - это вручную задавать `max-width`.

Один из вариантов это вручную следить за изменениями медиа запросов, это за вас может сделать `MediaObserver` из ядра `flex-layout`:

```
import { MediaObserver, MediaChange } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  public fxFlex: string = null;

  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {
    mediaObserver.asObservable().pipe(
      map((changes: MediaChange[]) => {
        return changes.map(({ mediaQuery }) => mediaQuery);
      }),
      map((queries: string[]) => {
        const matches = queries.find((query) => query === 'screen and (min-width: 1280px)');
        return !!matches;
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe((matches) => {
      if (matches) {
        this.fxFlex = 'calc(25% - 25px)';
      } else {
        this.fxFlex = 'calc(33% - 25px)';
      }
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

Дабы поиграться и понять, что представляет из себя поток `mediaObserver` - вы можете просто добавить `console.log(changes)`.

Тогда в самом шаблоне вы можете уже биндить саму переменную:

```
[fxFlex]="fxFlex" [style.max-width]="fxFlex"
```

Добавлю от себя - не полагайтесь полностью на этот пакет. Проще писать стили , используя обычный CSS. Этот пакет - убийца производительности.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ,  проблема была также в том что не правильно был задан `fxLayoutAlign` и если в строке 8 блоков по 20% то остальные 3 блока растягивались по всей ширине

Comment: по поводу пакета - говорю вам по опыту лучше не используйте его

Comment: легче задать какие-то общие классы типа `df jcc` (display: flex, justify-content: center) и реюзать их

Comment: Не использовать fxFlex ? мб есть аналоги ?

Comment: имею в виду в общем не юзать пакет `@angular/flex-layout`

Comment: Понял, еще такой вопрос, стоит ли использовать material 2 компоненты, если стили будут кастомные, сейчас их использую как основу или лучше смотреть в сторону clarity ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92116/discussion-between--and-overthesanity).